# Show $S_N$ converges to $S_\infty$ in distribution and it is normal, also converges in L^2, moreover almost surely

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

Suppose $a_n$, n=1,2,... is a sequence of numbers s.t. $s^2$= $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^2<\infty$, and $X_n$, n=1,2,... is a sequence of i.i.d. standard normal random variables. Set $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_nX_n$.

(1) Show that $S_N$ converges in distribution to a random variable $S_\infty$.         Moreover, $S_\infty$ has a Gaussian distibution with mean $0$ and variance $s^2$.

(2) Prove that $S_N$ indeed converges to $S_\infty$ in $L^2$.

(3)Show that, $S_N $ converges to $S_\infty$ almost surely.

for part (1) I got I got 
 $\phi_{S_n}$(t)=$\prod_{n=1}^{N}\phi_{X_n}$($a_n$t) . (2) Show we use Cauchy convergence (3) if it converge in $L_2$ can we apply Levy?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suppose you mean $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{\color{red}{N}} a_n X_n$. For (1) it would be a start to compute the characteristic function of $S_N$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}$. What do you get?

Comment: @saz I got  $\phi_{S_n}$(t)=$\prod_{n=1}^{N}\phi_{X_n}$($a_n$t)